# HOW TO JOIN TWO TABLES WITH 2 FIELDS

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, inner-join

i want to get VAL from table  B by joining A and B with the filled field, e.g:

A

```
F1,F2,F3
1,2,t1
2,3,t2
```

B

```
F1,F2,VAL
1,NULL,v1
NULL,2,v2
```

Output:

```
1,2,t1,v1
2,3,t2,v2
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join with `or`:

```
select a.*, b.val
from a inner join
     b
     on b.f1 = a.f1 or b.f2 = a.f2;
```

That typically has very poor performance.  An alternative is two `left join`s:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.val, b2.val)
from a left join
     b b1
     on b1.f1 = a.f1 left join
     b b2
     on b2.f2 = a.f2 and b1.f1 is null;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff,  i have another problem, it's possible to get the last date event per filled field?

Comment: @JamalMarouf . . . You should ask a *new* question with an appropriate explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*, b.val
from a
inner join b
    on (b.f1 is not null and b.f1 = a.f1)
    or (b.f2 is not null and b.f2 = a.f2)
```

Alternatively:

```
select a.*, b.val
from a
inner join b 
    on  (b.f1 is null or b.f1 = a.f1)
    and (b.f2 is null or b.f2 = a.f2)
```